# Passing values in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `Jquery/Javascript` function which calculates certain field values. One of the field returns a value in

```
function calcTotals() {
    marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);
}
```

I have another function with a `checkbox`

```
function recalcTotal() {
    var total12 = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        total12 += $(this).marginObj.value;
    });

    $('#total12').val(total12);
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function () {

    recalcTotal();
});
```

I need to pass the values from the marginObj.value to the next function that is total12 += $(this).marginObj.value; What iam trying to achieve is iam taking the values from marginObj.value and there is a checkbox, if i check the checbox it totals all the checked values and show it in grandTotal field.

```
  <input name="grandTotal" id="total12" readonly/>
```

Please check the complete script.
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z7L5y3s1/)

So what i want is there are some values in Margin with a checkbox. When i check any checkbox, its should total the selected checkboxes and show in the Grand Total field.

Comment: What is the html for checkbox?

Comment: Can you make a working code snippet in your post, create a fiddle or a codepen so we have a working example to work with?

Comment: <input type='checkbox' name='gt[]' id='gt[]'><input size='8' type='text' id='margin_for[]' name='margin_for[]' readonly> The values of margin_for is passing to marginObj.value..

Comment: @SkullDev. The code is too long. so am thinking how to post it.

Comment: I am guessing the issue is $(this).marginObj.value should be $(this).next("input").val().  Edited

Comment: i will try to shortened the code and put in fidle so that you can have a look.

Comment: some advice -- try to avoid jquery and additional libraries, look up plain javascript querySelectors, childNodes.length, etc. try to learn "functional" js where functions return things (even though you can edit a param object and the object will change everywhere else. "object oriented" javascript where you store variables either in a scope as a `var myVar` or in a context (object) like `this.myVar`. its a bit complex but once you get it, there's not a whole lot left to learn!

Comment: sure thank you for the advice. I will try to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the issue is getting the marginObj which is an input element after check box.

```
$(function () {
   recalcTotal();

   $("input[type='checkbox'").on("click", function () {
       recalcTotal();
    });

   function recalcTotal() {
        var total = 0.0;

        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            total += $(this).next("input").val() * 1.0;
        });

        $("#total").val(total.toFixed(3));
    }
});

<input type="text" id="total" readonly/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values"/><input type="text" readonly value="1"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="2"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="3"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="4"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="5"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="6"/> <br />
```

Comment: This code should work.  do not use .marginObj.value just use the code as is.

Comment: Its working fine. Just one more query. How will i make the totals to 3 decimals.

Comment: and one more query. If i dont select any checkbox, by default it should show the existing margin totals.

Comment: Its ok, i guess you are busy. Really really appreciate your help. Its really a great help to novices like me to get help and motivated from members like you. Really thankyou for your time...:)

Comment: @SanjuMenon Sorry I was away (different time zone)  :).  to make 3 decimal change * 1 to * 1.0 and to call recalcTotal() on page load.  see edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you are asking, but if you are simply trying to pass a value from one function to another, there are multiple approaches, but the simplest is to pass arguments to the function.

```
//this function supports 1 argument
function calcTotals( amount ) {
    //add 1 and return
    return amount + 1;
}

//calling this argument
var amount = 5;
var newAmount = calcTotals( amount );
```

Comment: Might be worth putting a `return` example from one function to another as well since OP seems fairly new.

Comment: i will try to shortened the code and put in fidle so that you can have a look.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have added my existing script in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

assuing  marginObj is globally accessible.

```
function recalcTotal() {
var total12 = 0;
$('input:checked').each(function () {
    total12 += $(this).marginObj.value;
});

$('#total12').val(total12);
}
 $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function () {
calcTotals(); -- will populate marginObj.value
recalcTotal();
});
```

Comment: i will try to shortened the code and put in fidle so that you can have a look.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have added my existing script in fiddle